# how to use socket.io expressjs electron to send information to the renderer process

Tags: node.js, express, installation, socket.io, electron

I got an electron application which uses expressjs for the (CRUD).
I need to send information from the backend not only from the main process file but from any other *.js file in the backend using socketio.

I have tried creating a connection between renderer and express server. I have been able to show information in the front end. The problem is that when i try to reuse the same connection to send more information ... i got too many connections open the application freezes.

ExpressServer.js

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import { Server } from "socket.io"
import http from "http"
const config = { port: process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 3001 }
const CURRENT_WORKING_DIR = process.cwd()

class ServerExpress {

constructor(){
this.expressApp = express()

this.expressApp.get('/*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))
})



this.server = http.createServer(this.expressApp)
this.server.listen(config.port, function() {
console.log(`Listening on port ${config.port}`);
 })

this.io = undefined
this.commSocket = undefined
this.socketid = undefined


bindings
this.connection = this.connection.bind(this)
this.com = this.com.bind(this)
this.getExpressApp = this.getExpressApp.bind(this)
this.connectionExecute = this.connectionExecute.bind(this)
this.getComSocket = this.getComSocket.bind(this)

this.connectionExecute()
this.expressApp.set("socketio", this.io)

}

async connectionExecute(){
    await this.connection()
}

  async connection(url = "http://localhost:3001"){

    console.log('Connection config started')
    this.io = await new Server(this.server, {
            cors: {
              origin: "http://localhost:3001",
              methods: ["GET", "POST  "]
            }
        })

  }

com(param= "somevalue"){
    new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      this.io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {     

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
          console.log('Disconnected from com socket.id: ', socket.id)
        })
      
        resolve(socket)
  
      })
    })
    .then((socket)=>{
      this.commSocket = socket
      this.socketid = socket.id
      this.commSocket.emit('api', { greeting: param }) // does not work from here
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.error(err)
    })

}

// I just want to call the emit event from socketio
async sendingInfoToRenderer(param){
   
  this.commSocket.to(this.socketid).emit("api", { greeting: 'getComSocket in express' })
    
}


} // Ends class

export default ServerExpress
```

In the main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, Tray, ipcMain } = require('electron')
import ServerExpress from './server/express.js'
import path from "path"

const eServer = await new ServerExpress()
await eServer.com('main')
eServer.sendingInfoToRenderer('main getCom Socket')
```

In the render.js

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client"
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001")

// client-side
socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("renderer socket.id: ", socket.id); 
  });

socket.on("api", (message)=>{
    console.log('Connection stablished')
    console.log(message)
})
```